# Is there a way to remotely copy something from one shared folder to another shared folder without relaying through my system?

Tags: windows-7, windows, file-transfer

I have a remote Windows 7 host with several shared folders.

```
\\foobox\shared1 = c:\FooFolder
\\foobox\shared2 - d:\FooFolder
```

If I connect to `\\foobox` via explorer on a remote windows system and try to copy items from one folder to another, I've noticed that it takes a long time (MUCH longer than copying the same items locally on foobox itself.  I presume that this is because foobox is sending my remote workstation the data and I'm sending it back.

Is there a way for foobox to do this more efficiently without requiring me to RDC in or use third-party tools?

Comment: No, you'll need a 3rd party tool, or to login to one of the machines in question to start the transfer.  Look into PSExec.

Comment: @terdon If he's one on machine, and he copies from one remote location to another, it HAS to go through his workstation, or it won't know how to get to the target computer.  I doubt any other OS works any differently when doing it that way.  SSH is equivalent to logging in via remote, which the OP seems to say he doesn't want to (or can't?) do (by saying no 'RDC').

Comment: FXP (variant of FTP) can accomplish the task, except windows explorer I believe does not support FXP (FTP yes, but not FXP). Like techie007 mentioned, PSEXEC and a script would work. Are you trying to Sync the folders? RSync...